# ContainsKey returns unit and not bool?

Tags: f#

It's odd to me that the following code throws a compile time error. I'm not sure why ContainsKey is returning unit. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) says it returns bool.

```
open System.Collections.Generic    

let mydict = new Dictionary<string,'a>()

if(mydict.ContainsKey "mykey") then
    mydict.["mykey"] = newkey
```

> error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
>       'bool'     but here has type
>       'unit'

Am I missing something here?

Comment: It's not `ContainsKey` that returns `bool`. It's the comparison operator `=` on the next line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if` is an expression so both branches must have the same type. If the `else` branch is not specified an empty one of type `unit` is inserted. This means your `then` branch must also have type `unit`. However `mydict.["mykey"] = newkey` has type `bool`. If you want to insert a new value for `mykey` you should use `<-` instead of `=`:

```
if(mydict.ContainsKey "mykey") then
    mydict.["mykey"] <- newkey
```